# React onClick event is not working on bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: reactjs, jsx, dropdown, toggle, react-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a dropdown menu in React.
The `<Dropdown></Dropdown>` is inside the `return()` of my component.

```
<Dropdown>
    <Dropdown.Toggle className="btn btn-dark">
        <i onClick={() => handleToggle()}>{icons['Menu']}</i>
    </Dropdown.Toggle>

     <Dropdown.Menu className="nav-container border-secondary-subtle border border-3">
          <Dropdown.Item href="#" className="nav-items">
              Dashboard
          </Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#" className="nav-items">
              Courses
          </Dropdown.Item>
     </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

```
import { Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = useState(false);
    const handleToggle = () =>{
        setShowDropdown(!showDropdown);
        console.log(showDropdown)
    }
```

Current behavior: On clicking the Menu icon, the Dropdown.Menu options are visible. But on clicking the menu icon again it is not getting hidden.

I have tried setting the onClick to Dropdown.Toggle and Dropdown. Both are not working. But the in console I can see the value of showDropdown flipping with each click.

I also tried this in onClick = {()=>setShowDropdown(!showDropdown)}

I saw in a few examples that they were not using any eventListeners but that dint work for me as well.

Also, I want the menu to not be visible after any of the menu items are clicked.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I had added a `display:block` in the class `nav-container`. After removing this the Dropdown is working as expected without any listeners.